# i keep getting cannot find -lbgi whenever i try to import graphics.h

Tags: c++, codeblocks, bgi

I think I've done everything needed for it to work, but I still keep getting cannot find -lbgi; I tried the tutorials for graphics.h and followed them directly, but I still keep getting cannot find -lbgi. I'm using codeblocks 20.03 images:https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOnYO.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/agvcR.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3NQA.png

Comment: Remove `-lbgi` you already link to the library by full path. With that said this may compile but crash unless you have a compiler from the early 2000s.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could remove the library of libbgi with compile option, or try to add the library path of libbgi in IDE.